# CSS Precedence - which one trumps?

Tags: css

About to have an exam and I am going through the previous exam that we have been given.

The question:
When two or more style sheet rules apply to the same element, which of the following types of rules will take precedence?

a. Any declaration with browser origin
b. Normal declaration with user origin
c. Normal declaration with author origin
d. Document-level declaration

So would the answer be c or d? I am guessing d because c is a normal declaration and not important but I can't really get a definitive answer anywhere

Cheers

Comment: what makes you to not try  first ?

Comment: What is a document-level declaration? Is it referring to an inline style?

Comment: @BoltClock document level declaration means levels of declaring multiple stylesheets...so it will pick up styles from last linked stylesheet

Comment: @Mr. Alien: I don't think so. That's an author stylesheet, which means it falls into category c.

Comment: @BoltClock Now you are confusing me, but what right is the styles are picked up from last declared link for stylesheet...

Comment: In that case, the question has to clarify the meaning of "document-level declaration"...

Comment: Document-level is referring to styles declared in the head of the document

Comment: @user1667474 done, than my answer is correct

Comment: Is this standard terminology? Wouldn't a user stylesheet take precedence over all of the others?

Comment: @Blender he asked what if 2 user-defined stylesheet applies styles to a same element..

Comment: @Blender: I've never heard of a "document-level declaration", but the rest is pretty much standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order

Comment: @Blender: And no, a user stylesheet won't take precedence over all the others, because it is (usually) used for overriding styles globally on a per-user basis, whereas author stylesheets are specific to the site that they're authored for. This is why `!important` is most useful in user stylesheets (and I believe it was *designed* for use in user stylesheets) for overriding site-specific styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reffering the [CSS Cascading](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade).

So, from the link

> Style sheets may have three different origins: author, user, and user agent.

and the precedence between them is as follows

> By default, rules in author style sheets have more weight than rules in user style sheets. Precedence is reversed, > however, for "!important" rules. All user and author rules have more weight than rules in the UA's default style 
>   sheet.

The cascading order is defined by ascending order of precedence

```
user agent declarations
user normal declarations
author normal declarations
author important declarations
user important declarations
```

The [CSS specificity Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) later come into picture.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `Document-level declaration`, it will be applying styles to the element which are declared in the last linked stylesheet

Test case

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>hello<!-- Color applied will be green --></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

`stylesheet1.css`

```
div {
    color: red;
}
```

`stylesheet2.css`

```
div {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Am `100%` sure, it will pick up the styles from the stylesheet which is linked last

Comment: @NullPointer: What? You can't [lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) answers.

Comment: @NullPointer haha thanks and (Daniel) he meant that I am sure or not... ;)

Comment: @BoltClock its wasnt about the locking answer

Comment: Those are external -  the precedence rules on that are 1 - inline 2 - document-level (in the head of the document) 3 external The other rules referred to are in this order 1 - Important declaration of user origin 2 - Important declaration of author origin 3 - Normal declaration of author origin 4 - Normal declaration of user origin 5 Any declaration with browser origin

Comment: @user1667474 you said 2 stylesheets, actually you asked a wrong question, highest level is `inline`

Comment: one or more style sheet rules - not one or more stylesheets

Comment: See make it simple, for 2 stylesheets, I've already answered you, and whatever you do, `inline` style is the king of all...

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is document level

Comment: @user1667474 Did you understood my answer?

Comment: guys you should start chat instead making long chat here

Comment: You didn't answer the question that I asked Mr Alien

Answer (score 1):

The exam question is incorrect, as exam questions often are. The expression “Document-level declaration” is not a proper term, and it has multiple interpretations. Moreover, it uses the word “normal” without specifying its meaning, but probably you are right in guessing that it means “without `!important`”.

The answer is “undecided”, since “a” includes a browser style sheet rule with `!important`, which trumps “b” and “c” (and “d” unless it means something that may have `!important`), but it would be incorrect to say that “a” generally trumps the others. **Edit:** The specifications might be read so that browser style sheets cannot have `!important` or that it does not have an effect in them, but at least Firefox html.css uses `!important` (obscurely).

My bet is that the author of the exam did not think of the possible of an `!important` rule in a browser style sheet, and you are therefore supposed to answer “c”.

**Edit:** Option “d” is there probably just to confuse students, since if it means a style sheet embedded in an HTML document, it’s a special case of author style sheel, and being embedded does not affect the cascade rules (among style sheets embedded with `style` and linked with `link`, it is the placement of the HTML element that matters, not the embedded vs. linked thing).

Comment: In the uni course the context of document-level means the style is in the head of the document

Comment: The author is aware of important, the answer is not a as that rule comes after normal declarations (number 5 - Any declaration of browser origin) which normal declaration of author origin trumps (it is number 3 on that particular set of rules above number 4 which is b in the multi-choice)

Comment: @user1667474: In that case, it is ambiguous with c, because a style in the head of the document is part of an author stylesheet. If it's in `<style>` tags, it's an *internal* author stylesheet, whereas if it's linked in a file, it's an *external* author stylesheet.

Comment: I think I'll check with the Lecturer as there is bound to be a similar type of question. Thanks for all your input